# Retrieving data in a Core Data Relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, uiview

I am working on a project which provides a way to collect data about rooms at a specific address. I have set up a relationship in the data model between the rooms and address tables. The project currently presents a `UITableView` of addresses which the user is able to drill down via address to another `UItableView` to view rooms.

This is where I am clueless. If there are no rooms, a custom `UIView` is presented to enter the room data. The user enters the data in the `UIView` for each data point and then presses save. The `IBAction` for the save button currently sets the value for each key in the related table. I am assuming it is here that I need to establish the relationship between an address and its rooms, but I cannot find the proper way to do this. I have tried NSSet setWithObject in the setValue method:

```
[newRoom setValue:[NSSet setWithObject:_address] roomName.text forKey:@"roomName"];
```

but `Xcode` wants me to insert a colon between `roomName` and text.

Ultimately I want the user to be able to choose an address and manage room data for that address, but I am unsure how to establish the relationship between the address and its rooms.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `Address` to `Room` relationship is one to many: each `Address` can have many `Rooms`, whereas each `Room` relates to only one `Address`.  So the `Address` entity should have a `rooms` property to represent the relationship, and the `Room` entity should likewise have an `address` property. (If you have used different names for these properties, amend below where necessary).

When the user selects a row in the table view of addresses, you determine the corresponding `Address` object.  Let's call that `chosenAddress`.  Your second table view should then display only those `Room` objects that relate to the `chosenAddress`.  When you create a new `Room` object, let's call it `newRoom`, you can establish the relationship to `chosenAddress` with:

```
[newRoom setValue:chosenAddress forKey:@"address"];
```

or, if you have created NSManagedObject subclasses for `Address` and `Room`:

```
newRoom.address = chosenAddress;
```

Note that CoreData will automatically set the inverse relationship, adding `newRoom` to the set given by `chosenAddress.rooms`.

Comment: Let me see if I am following you. Is chosenAddress an attribute in the Room entity? Does this act like a foreign key in the SQL world? I don't know why I am so confused in getting this to work properly.

Comment: Yes, kind of.  The `address` **property** (of the `Room` entity) fills the role of foreign key.  CoreData actually hides the foreign key implementation details, so rather than setting  `newRoom.secondaryKey = chosenAddress.primaryKey`, you can just use `newRoom.address = chosenAddress`.  CoreData does the  magic under the hood.